# How to prevent kivy application from becoming non responsive while performing some backend functions

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy

I have a kivy application, which needs to download data of the internet at some point during run time, the problem is when the function for downloading data runs the app becomes non responsive, occasionally it can take up to a couple of minutes to download the data. It does later on after downloading the required files continue to work properly, however anyone who doesn't know about this bug would easily exit the app as soon as it goes non responsive.

Here is some sample code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
import datetime
from duka.core.utils import TimeFrame
import duka.app.app as import_data

class btnFloatie(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        btn = Button(text="Download files")
        btn.bind(on_press=self.get_files)
        self.add_widget(btn)

    def get_files(self):
        start_date = datetime.date(2020,02,02)
        end_date = datetime.date(2020,03,02)

        import_data(["AUDCAD"], start_date, end_date, 1, TimeFrame.H4, ".", True)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return btnFloatie

MainApp().run()
```

What can i do so that the app does not crash while downloading data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data download is a blocking function call, so once the app starts doing it it doesn't get around to other normal tasks (checking for input, updating the gui) until it's done.

The simple solution is to do your download in a thread. That means the main thread, which is doing those gui tasks, is not blocked and the app will remain responsive.